# How to access a tabhost with multiple tabs of the same Activity?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I'm developing an "Scorer Application" for a board game. The game can host between 2 and 8 players. So I have created a Tabhost with 8 tabs of the same activity(player.class). And it works :)

```
private void newTab(int i) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Player.class);       

    TabSpec spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec("Player" + i);

    spec.setIndicator("Player " + i);

    spec.setContent(intent);

    mTabHost.addTab(spec);

}
```

but the problem comes if I want to reset the scores of everyone. So I have created a Menu with  onCreateOptionsMenu() with the item "Reset Scores". But I dont know how to access the Tabs to set the individual scores to '0'.

I have tried :

Player.setScores(0); // but it only change the score of the last created tab(Predictably)

any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Player Activity, you can acces your TabActivity by calling [getParent()](http://d.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getParent%28%29). 
Then you just have to call [getTabHost()](http://d.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html#getTabHost%28%29). This way you have full access to each sub activity of your TabActivity.

Comment: Thank you. i did that String tabTag = tabHost.getCurrentTabTag();
Activity activity = getLocalActivityManager().getActivity(tabTag);
But I cannot access the function "setScores" from the activity.

Comment: How can I access a function from a Class from its Activity?

Comment: To call your "setScores" method you have to cast your activity like this : ((Player)getLocalActivityManager().getActivity(tabTag)).setScores(120);